# GWT CELLTABLE : How to add empty row in celltable with different celltype

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

How to add empty row in celltable with different celltype ?

4 columns present in my celltable i.e. DatePickerCell,EditTextCell,NumberCell,SelectionCell

I can able to set record values in cell with different celltype.

I want to add empty row with different cell type in celltable also want few of them editable and rest are non-editable.

I want to do MassUpdate in Celltable.So I required 1st row as empty because whenever I will change value in particular cell which is editable then all values in that column  should be updated immediately

Suppose I edited value in edittextcell of 1st empty row then all values in same column should be edited immediately.

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two questions here: 1) how to add a row with a custom cell type - I believe that is impossible with CellTable, since it operates on column level and each column has its Cell type defined during addition. You can always have a custom cell for that, but it will be only in that one column, not for "entire row". 2) how to mass update all values of the table after one cell was edited - you need to add an edit event handler to your EditTextCells and there just update your underlying data list for CellTable (and then refresh the table maybe).